# gradle returns subproject as null

Tags: java, gradle

I want to iterate over project's subprojects and for every someproject call `JavaExec` task with certain parameters.

Project structure is like this

```
rootProject\
settings.gradle
 build.gradle
    semiRootProject\
    build.gradle
        application\
        build.gradle
        proj1\
        gradle.properties
        proj2\
        gradle.properties
```

I am trying to do it like this but it throws an error

```
task packageJar(dependsOn: build) {    
    project(":semiRootProject").subprojects.each { 

        logger.lifecycle "Project name: " it.name
        if (it.name != "application") {

            doLast {
                javaexec {
                    main = 'com.xxxx.util.KiePackageCreator'
                    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + it.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
                    args = [ it.name, it.group , it.version, it.buildDir ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is

```
Cannot get property 'it' on null object
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, you're trying to pass a part of the message text as a loggerparameter, so just try to modify this line:

```
logger.lifecycle "Project name: " it.name
```

To

```
logger.lifecycle "Project name: " + it.name
```

Comment: Now I got error `No such property: sourceSets for class: org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction_Decorated`

Comment: @user1432980 seems here `classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` the `sourceSets` are taken as some parameter of the current task. May be you have to do it as `classpath = it.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`